# Probability of drawing a ball

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $n$ be as follows:  $$\begin{cases} n\geq 2\\ n\in \mathbb{N} \end{cases}$$
  A box contains 
      one ball numbered 1,
      two balls numbered 2,
       .
        .
         .
           $n$ balls numbered $n$

> We randomly draw one ball from the box (assuming $n$ is even)

What is the probability of the following events ?

A: Drawing a ball with an even number on it

B: Drawing a ball with an odd number on it

Comment: Hints: $(1)$ How many balls are there in the box?; $(2)$ Of those, how many are even?

Comment: 1+2+......+n =n(n+1)/2

Comment: That's your denominator (since all balls are equally likely).

Comment: Next do the count for even. Note the common factor.

Comment: When you get an answer, check it against small values of $n$ to make sure you didn't make an algebraic error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be the number on the ball drawn, then $$P(N~\text{is even})=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}P(N=2k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\frac{2k}{n(n+1)/2}$$